# Будет ли "а иногда и нападениях" уточнением? Или запятая в конце вовсе не нужна?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

Наткнулся в сети:
"В ряде интернет СМИ распространяется информация о провокациях, а иногда и нападениях, на пунктах сбора подписей для выдвижения в кандидаты в депутаты N-ской городской думы.
Прошу вас принять меры..."
Интонационно вроде как не нужна, но имеются какие-то сомнения.
Заранее спасибо!
P. S. Каким правилом это регулируется?

Answer (score 1):

*В ряде интернет СМИ распространяется информация о провокациях, **а иногда и нападениях** на пунктах сбора подписей для выдвижения в кандидаты в депутаты N-ской городской думы.*

Здесь лучше считать падежные формы **однородными**. Составной союз ***А ИНОГДА И*** синонимичен союзу  ***А ТАКЖЕ***, он дифференцируют однородные отношения, придавая второму дополнению присоединительный характер.

Обособление в этом случае также возможно, если е**сть необходимость подчеркнуть уточняющий характер второго дополнения**, но здесь лучше этого не делать. Однородные отношения смотрятся более логично.